# how to write a linq to sql query for getting last record?

Tags: linq-to-sql

REcords are entering like this.

```
id     message    timestamp
1      hi         12-12-2012 11.00
2      gii        12-12-2012 11.01
```

How to write the query for getting new message record based on timestamp?i mean last record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Max` method.

```
DateTime[] arr = new DateTime[] 
    { DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), DateTime.Today.AddDays(2) };
DateTime lastEntity = arr.Max(x => x.Date);  // equals DateTime.Today.AddDays(2)
```